# lua love2d not finding main.lua file

Tags: lua, love2d

file exists, and I just love is giving me "basic" window

Basically error is this:

```
Error

[love "boot.lua"]:323: Cannot load game at path 'C:/Users/bbaku/Desktop/random_folder/Love/main.lua'.
Make sure a folder exists at the specified path.


Traceback

[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'
[C]: in function 'error'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

main.lua exists, and location is correct too. I think I set up love2D correctly and added a correct variable.

Comment: I am not using LÖVE/LuaJIT very often on Windows but the Paths on em should look like: ```start love C:\Users\bbaku\Desktop\random_folder\Love``` and because of coercion from/inside Lua you/we have to use: ```path = 'C:\\Users\\bbaku\\Desktop\\random_folder\\Love'``` - Because the Backslash is used for escaping ( like for newline \n or other escape sequences ) by Lua

Comment: Ecxeption is the Lua longstring Definition where you can place also normal whitespace like in the HTML Element ```<pre>Foo Bar</pre>``` than you can do with Lua: ```loadfile([[C:\Users\bbaku\Desktop\random_folder\Love\main.lua]])``` or similar things.

Answer (score 1):

`Make sure a folder exists at the specified path.`

The path selected however, ends on a file. Set the path to go to Love/ instead of main.lua.

(This may not work as an answer, but I am unable to comment due to reputation)